# Visual Studio compile "filter" as C and "filters" groups as C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I have written the majority of my project in C++. However there are several "filters" or folders which need to be compiled as C and linked to the project. How can I configure this within VStudio? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried solving this yourself? what did you find?

Comment: I did, couldn't phrase it properly on google. I also snooped into the configuration (right click). Wouldn't have posted it otherwise. Also Im glad I did as its something MS can add as a feature not being able to set groups/filters to a certain compile type.

Comment: Also turns out that VStudio recognises the files automatically as either C/C++ based on whether the files are *.c *.cpp etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Language property by right-clicking on the individual files and setting `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Compile` As To `Compile As C (/TC)`. No such facility for the filter are present though.